# Error: Cannot move to subdirectory of itself ? Raspi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pi-3

I am running this simple script and I am trying to create a cron job so that the file gets copied to my thumbdrive (with the new name)

```
  sudo cp /home/pi/NewLog.log /media/usb
  sleep 20
  cd /media/usb
  sudo mv -f NewLog.log NewLog-$(date '+%FT%T').log
  sudo cp /dev/null /home/pi/NewLog.log
```

But I am getting the error

mv: cannot move ‘NewLog.log’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘NewLog-2016-05-04T14:19:24.log’

I have auto mounted my USB in Pi3 using sudo apt-get install usbmount
It gets mounted to the directory /media/usb

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try searching on google for your question? I get about 270,000 results. Please use this forum for stuff you cannot search for, and that are pi-specific.

Comment: If you cannot help that is fine. They are many more to help me 

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281062/cannot-mv-to-a-subdirectory-of-itself?noredirect=1#comment488937_281062

I am not a kid to post questions without googling ! Thanks

Comment: You should be taken out back and shot for this: `cp /dev/null /home/pi/NewLog.log`, lol.  If you want to truncate the contents, use `echo -n > NewLog.log`.   Q.v. `man echo` about `-n`.

Comment: lol , thanks for the suggestion I have changed it @goldilocks

Answer (score 0):

Contra JayEye, it's not clear just from this why you get that error.  You can:

```
cp /path/to/file /path/to/directory
```

And if `file` is a file it should be a file in `directory` too.   However, if you've been using that zany thing with `/dev/null` prior to this, all bets are off.

You could save yourself a step this way:

```
cp -f /home/pi/NewLog.log /media/usb/NewLog-$(date '+%FT%T').log
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -n > /home/pi/NewLog.log
fi
```

This will also guarantee that if `/media/usb` doesn't exist or isn't a directory you will get an error indicating such.  The `if` clause then ensures you don't loose the contents of `NewLog.log` if `cp` fails (the `$?` variable for POSIX shells such as bash is the exit status of the last command, and for `cp` it will be 0 only if there are no errors).

Note I've left out `sudo` here; if this is a system cron job you don't need it (they run root).  If it isn't, then use it as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you ! So I ran your script and got this error,,,,,,,,,cp: cannot create regular file ‘/media/usb/NewLog-2016-05-04T18:30:04.log’: Invalid argument

Comment: What kind of filesystem is on the USB device (ext, ntfs, vfat)?  What happens if you `sudo touch /media/usb/NewLog-2016-05-04T18:30:04.log`?

Comment: touch: setting times of ‘/media/usb/NewLog-2016-05-04T18:30:04.log’: No such file or directory.....I got this error when I tried touch......

Comment: I did fsck /media/usb...................

fsck from util-linux 2.25.2

e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)

fsck.ext2: Is a directory while trying to open /media/usb0

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Comment: I've never been a fan of or used automounting, which I think usually ends up involving a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) for normal user access; that may have something to do with it but I wouldn't know.  Can you actually `cd /media/usb; ls -l`, etc?

Comment: Yes I can ! I can even cp the file, but only mv doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm flummoxed. :(

Comment: There is absolutely nothing pi-specific in this question. Furthermore, the OP did not even include a long listing of their problem directory, or any other information to help debugging.

I'm all for helping noobs -- I was one once, back in the 14th century, but seriously, something that has 270K hits on Google should not appear here. All it does is reduce the SNR on the forum.

Comment: I have a 16GB SD card, so i am gonna copy it to the card instead of the USB. I even tried mounting it and tried to do mv (manual mount) it still shows the same error !

Comment: @JayEye Our overlap w/ U&L is a [gray area](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/622/5538) (that's been discussed beyond that example) and in my own words "discretionary".  Unfortunately, it takes 3000 rep to vote "close as off-topic" (unfortunately because we don't have many active users in that category).  I'm prone to agree with you about that, but not absolutely (hence my "discretionary" attitude).  WRT this particular question, you may have found 270,000 google hits but I'd be impressed if you could actually use that to *provide an answer* here, because the problem is FUBAR.

Comment: @goldilocks I got the solution to this problem. See this link,    http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281062/cannot-mv-to-a-subdirectory-of-itself/281178#281178

Comment: Sounds right to me --  this is why I asked earlier what kind of filesystem is on the device.

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you for all your effort and help !!!!